# How to change autolink

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, joomla2.5

in my forum, I'm trying to stop links from converting into clickbale links and place a custom text language instead that says Links Not Allowed.

This seems to be the code that creates the clickable links.  My question, is it possible to convert the urls to non-clickable text that says "Spam - Links Not Allowed"

```
public function parseUrl($params) {
    $url = $params['url'];
    $text = $params['text'];
```

If I remove this last line, it seems to make the links disappear, however I would like to display a custom message instead.  Sorry if this is a basic question, my code knowledge is at a beginner level.

Comment: try $text = "Message...";

Comment: and `$url="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: Hi, $text = "Message..."; did change the language of the link, but the $url="javascript:void(0);" caused a 500 Internal Server Error unfortunately..  So I can use the second part or there is an error with it I believe.

Comment: Hi Thank you, this worked..  There was just a typo, I changed ;" to "; and instead of javascript:void I used a page to my sites Forum Rules page!  Works very well for this purpose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just server side action, for this reason you should call JS function, so, at first change your php code to this :

```
$url = $params['javascript:myfunction();'];
```

and then in client side for javascript write this :

```
function myfunction(){
alert('not allowed!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$text = $params['text'];`

replace "text" with "spam - links not allowed."

In terms of how to make it not clickable, I need to see where the link is actually used.

Comment: I replaced 'text" with "spam-links not allowed." but didn't work.